# Removing trailing slashes from certain URL's in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I recently moved my blog from using WordPress over to using Jekyll (I like the idea of static files for my blog). I'm using Nginx (was using it with PHP-FPM before) and have things setup to handle stuff. I've encountered one problem I do not know how to fix.

The URL structure I'm using is

```
/atthekeyboard/YYYY/MM/DD/title-of-post
```

I have about 5 years worth of blog posts that have been indexed by Google and they are

```
/attheykeyboard/YYYY/MM/DD/title-of-post/
```

I want to rewrite all the older calls with the trailing slash to use the non-trailing slash URL until Google indexes all the new stuff.

Here is the nginx config stuff I have already:

```
    location /atthekeyboard {
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri.html $uri/ /notfound.html;
    }
```

I'm using try_files because the posts are actually saved as title-of-post.html and I didn't want the .html part.

Thanks in advance for your advice and solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should remove the trailing slash and then let Nginx reparse the location blocks.

```
location ~ ^(/atthekeyboard/.+)/$ {
    set $noslash $1;
    rewrite ^ $noslash permanent;
}
```

Comment: I added that in and I get '[emerg]: unknown "noslash" variable' when I run nginx -t

Comment: @GrumpyCanuck Edited it, should be compatible with older nginx versions now.

Comment: sorry, still not working :( Here's a paste of the [configuration file](http://pastie.org/1618758)  I had to add a $ to noslash in the set command in order to get nginx to stop complaining. In case it matters, I'm using nginx version 0.7.67

Comment: @GrumpyCanuck it was me being stupid, the configuration actually does work but I had forgotten the permanent flag on rewrite so it did an internal redirect instead of an external one. So while it redirected you couldn't actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

i think [the HTTPRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) is what you are looking for

Comment: Duh, I should've mentioned that I do know about the HTTPRewriteModule but I have been unable to figure out the proper rewrite rule to make it happen.